# Macbook Pro WiFi Painfully Slow on Corporate Network, PC Works Fine

Tags: network, wifi

Whenever I bring my 2015 Macbook Pro to a certain corporate environment and try to use WiFi there, it is painfully slow. At times, Google takes 5-10 seconds to load. Now, a Windows machine works just fine on this same network. What is more, when another person tries to use his 2016 Macbook Pro, he encounters the same problem.

Does anyone know what settings or configurations we can check either on the Macs or the network to fix this?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this setting, it helped me in the same situation :) In the network settings change the address of DNS servers to Google's ones: 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4

For this go to `Settings > Network > Advanced... > DNS` > press <kbd>+</kbd> and enter DNS address.

[image]

Or, vice versa, you may ask your system administrator for any specific DNS and probably proxy settings that your company might have due to security reasons and then enter them in the Proxy tab.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, did this solve the issue only for the Google site or for all of them? I used Google as an example, but other sites are phenomenally slow as well.

Comment: For all of them, of course.

Comment: Thanks! It made it much faster, albeit there is still a delay of about a second, which is due to WiFi, I guess.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you think this has solved your problem to your satisfaction, then you may consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: I did. However, I am still open to hear other ideas :-)

Comment: Looks like it reverted back to the slow ways. I will take off the correct answer mark in case someone else may have a suggestion.

Comment: Just FYI: you can mark any answer as accepted ANY time, even if there are 100s of answers posted. You can also change which answer is accepted at any time too. And second: did it revert back by itself? Didn't you change / do anything?